# ViewPart not showing in Eclipse Juno

Tags: user-interface, view, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I tried to create a plugin for a clean Eclipse Juno for RCP RAP. Tried to create a basic View extention. But the ViewPart I created doesn't show in the views... it works fine in Indigo.

So I was wondering is there something I need to adjust? Or is creating ViewParts for Eclipse Juno different as in Indigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.... Views will not automaticly be placed under the Others Category... therefore every View's category has to be filled in